# traverse array of hashes in ruby (jekyll)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am writing a plugin for Jekyll so that I can compare some data on products,
and I am returning array of hashes like so to be available in my template:

```
data = [{"current"=>"0.4mA", "power"=>"15w"}, {"current"=>"1A", "power"=>"5w"}]
```

But now, when I traverse them using `liquid`:

```
<table>
{% for h in data %}
    <tr>
    {% for p in h %}
        <td>{{ p[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ p[1] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I am not able to list properties side by side, as I am passing through hashes
one at a time, so I end up having them one below the other instead.

What should I do from plugin to prepare the data the other way around, so that I would be
able to do what I want in my template?

EDIT:

So to clear up a bit, how to obtain following structure from the above array
of hashes using pure ruby?:

```
p1['current'] = '0.4mA'
p1['power'] = '15w'
... *may have more of these, depending on number of key:value pairs in the hash
p1['...'] = '...'

p2['current'] = '1A'
p2['power'] = '5w'
... *may have more of these, depending on number of key:value pairs in the hash
p2['...'] = '...'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the properties displayed in rows (eg, one row for 'current', one row for 'power', etc) and you don't want to make any changes to the display template, you can transform your data hash in Ruby like this - one of the following (maybe both) should work with your template:

If you know that every hash in `data` will have all the keys, you can take the keys from the first element:

```
keys = data[0].keys
```

OR if hashes in data might omit keys if the data is not meaningful, you can get all the distinct keys in `data`

```
keys = data.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq

new_data_array = keys.map { |a| data.map { |d| d[a] } }
=> [["0.4mA", "1A"], ["15w", "5w"]]

new_data_hash = Hash[keys.map {|a| [a, data.map { |d| d[a] }] }]
=> {"current"=>["0.4mA", "1A"], "power"=>["15w", "5w"]}
```

Here's how to bypass the data array and just get the values straight from h1 and h2 in one line:

```
Hash[(h1.keys & h2.keys).map {|a| [a, [h1, h2].map { |d| d[a] }] }]
=> {"current"=>["0.4mA", "1A"], "power"=>["15w", "5w"]}

(h1.keys & h2.keys).map {|a| [h1, h2].map { |d| d[a] } }
=> [["0.4mA", "1A"], ["15w", "5w"]]
```

Comment: But I will have arbitrary names for keys, and variable number of them, so how to map with those?

Comment: I solved that using `data[0].keys.to_a` instead of hardcoded values, as they will always be identical in both hashes becase it is intersection of other two product hashes on their common keys.

Comment: I just updated my answer with the same, along with an alternate solution if your future data set has missing keys for some values

Comment: Here is what I have before, and that way getting my `data` array:

`intersection = h1.keys & h2.keys`
`data = [h1, h2].map { |h| h.select{ |k,_| intersection.include? k }}`

So I am contstructing it from two hashes, based on their common keys,
would there be a way of doing all at once with this transformation you have shown?

Hashes are allowed to have different keys, and an arbitrary number of them,
also one Hash can have more or less key:value pairs than the other one.

Comment: I made an update to my wnswer to get the data directly from h1 and h2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the syntax for liquid, but I assume `{% <ruby code> %}`, and `{{ <ruby code> }}` are analogous to .erb's `<% <ruby code> %>`, and `<%= <ruby code> %>`. In that case you can do the following:

['current', 'power'].each do |a| data.each do |d| puts d[a] end end

```
<table>
{% ['current', 'power'].each do |a|  %}
    <tr>
    {% data.each do |d| %}
        <td>{{ a[d] }}</td>
    {% end %}
    </tr>
{% end %}
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately liquid is not capable of doing that. My question is regarding how to restructure data in plugin instead, using pure ruby, then pass it to a template engine.. so that I would be able to traverse the data the way I need to.